# provide credentials in nuget command line parameters

Tags: nuget

We have an nuget server hosted in azure that only allow certain people to create packages.

If I run nuget command line, I get asked to provide username and password. Is there a possibility to provide username and password in command line?

I tried something such as -User or -UserName, but I get `Unknown option: '-User'`

```
nuget push -Source "XXX" -ApiKey VSTS -noninteractive mypackage.*.nupkg -User myUsername
```

Is there a way to provide credentials from command line?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You have to change the NuGet.config you use. That is possible from the [command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#sources):

```
nuget sources add -Name "MyExample" -Source "XXX" -username "Y" -password "Z"
```

The password will be stored encrypted in the config file and can only be decrypted in the same user context as it was encrypted.

Comment: If you need to update your password, you can do the following: `nuget sources update -Name "MyExample -username "Y" -password "New"`

Comment: this will update your global nuget.config unless you specify which config file you wish to update using the `-configFile "path to config\Nuget.Config"` flag

Comment: This is great, but how can I suppress the error when the name already exists? It messes up my CI build. I tried -verbosity quiet but that does nothing.

Comment: @Ben Power Try to use the "nuget sources remove -Name "MyExample" command first?

Comment: Thanks Jeroen that worked, but it's a bit of a hack though!

Comment: For anyone wondering, this makes changes to the file at `%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`.

Comment: I am getting Exited with code 1 if i change push to sources add in nuget command

Comment: @thegautamnayak Have a look [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6439). If it is still a problem: post a new question.

Answer (score 10):

Use PAT (Personal Access Token) as the password. Make sure that PAT has packaging read and write permission.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using an Azure Pipelines build file and trying to push to a private feed, you can use these snippets, just make sure to update `$VARIABLES` and indentation as-needed:

```
      - task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
        displayName: "Auth NuGet"
        name: Nuget_Authenticate
        inputs:
          nuGetServiceConnections: '$PROJECT_SETTINGS_SERVICE_CONNECTION_NAME'
          forceReinstallCredentialProvider: true

      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        name: pushNuGetPkg
        displayName: "Push NuGet"
        inputs:
          command: 'push'
          packagesToPush: '$(Build.Repository.Localpath)\Packages\*.nupkg'
          nuGetFeedType: 'external'
          publishFeedCredentials: '$ARTIFACTS_FEED_NAME'
          publishVstsFeed: '$AZURE_ORGANIZATION_NAME/$ARTIFACTS_FEED_NAME'
```

You may also need to set these env-vars up in your ADO Project's `Library` -> `Defaults` section. Make sure the second one is securely masked with the Lock icon.

`NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED`: `true`

`VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS`: `{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://$AZURE_ORG_NAME.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/$ARTIFACTS_FEED_NAME/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"$USERNAME", "password":"$PAT"}]}`

Answer (score 3):

For Using PAT(Personal Access Token) As Credential, you can use this code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="ChequeNuget" value="http://192.168.11.23:6700/DefaultCollection/Framework/_packaging/ChequeNuget/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <ChequeNuget>
      <add key="Username" value="ChequeNuget" />
      <add key="Password" value="AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAFyfr+GavvkSgtlD+6FbrwQAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAABHbg6o2T6HHgjyud+purjkcwLoK1OH2tQI3TZc3T6wfgAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAADnEEVK46WCJAwou/6Gb2ZudmbEJoPoFUqqyK32yf1OYUAAAABlnx7sfP37M/Kblf7VTN2lD3kTiKjRdr0GPCtrLBxGE6pXCbnBY/E1vIrP8S2Ci8HkMW6SgnSkvSACfliZWzoDQAAAAI0xvaQX2XsnjOuDExXf+tLzcdsDK9ZJNen/f4oMbWejc/zytb7D+oczJmrmRbvKBLBC9nGlK2/JfVZii39euMU=" />
      <add key="ValidAuthenticationTypes" value="basic" />
    </ChequeNuget>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

For updating password use the command below:

```
nuget sources update -ValidAuthenticationTypes basic -Name ChequeNuget -UserName "ChequeNuget" -Password [Personal Access Token]
```