# How do you restore private NuGet packages from private VSTS feeds with Cake

Tags: .net-core, nuget, azure-devops, cakebuild

I have a task which restores our NuGet package for our dotnet core application:

```
Task("Restore-Packages")
    .Does(() =>
{
    DotNetCoreRestore(sln, new DotNetCoreRestoreSettings {
        Sources = new[] {"https://my-team.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/my-feed/nuget/v3/index.json"},
        Verbosity = DotNetCoreVerbosity.Detailed
    });
});
```

However when run on VSTS it errors with the following:

```
2018-06-14T15:10:53.3857512Z          C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://my-team.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/my-feed/nuget/v3/index.json. [D:\a\1\s\BitCoinMiner.sln]
2018-06-14T15:10:53.3857956Z        C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [D:\a\1\s\BitCoinMiner.sln]
```

How do I authorize access for the build agent to our private VSTS?

Comment: What's the result if you put nuget configure file (include credentials) to the current folder.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980240/provide-credentials-in-nuget-command-line-parameters (the file is in C:\Users\{account}\AppData\Roaming\NuGet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I literally just had this same problem, apparently the build agents in VSTS can't get to your private VSTS feed without an access token so you are going to have to create a Personal Access Token in VSTS and provide that to the built in Cake method to add an authenticated VSTS Nuget feed as one of the sources. Here, I have wrapped it in my own convenience Cake method that checks to see if the package feed is already present, if not, then it adds it:

```
void SetUpNuget()
{
    var feed = new
    {
        Name = "<feedname>",
        Source = "https://<your-vsts-account>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/<yournugetfeed>/nuget/v3/index.json"
    };

    if (!NuGetHasSource(source:feed.Source))
    {
        var nugetSourceSettings = new NuGetSourcesSettings
                             {
                                 UserName = "<any-odd-string>",
                                 Password = EnvironmentVariable("NUGET_PAT"),
                                 Verbosity = NuGetVerbosity.Detailed
                             };     

        NuGetAddSource(
            name:feed.Name,
            source:feed.Source,
            settings:nugetSourceSettings);
    }   
}
```

and then I call it from the "Restore" task:

```
Task("Restore")
    .Does(() => {       
        SetUpNuget();
        DotNetCoreRestore("./<solution-name>.sln"); 
});
```

Personally, I prefer to keep PATs away from the source control so here I am reading from env vars. In VSTS you can create an environment variable under the Variables tab of your CI build configuration.

[image]

Hope this helps! Here is a [link](https://cakebuild.net/dsl/nuget/) to Cake's documentation.

Comment: Thanks, managed to solve it a similar way but you can enable a one time API token on the build agent `ACCESS_TOKEN` and use this as the password instead. Thus not needing a personal token.

Comment: Ah! Will check that out too. Nice one!

Comment: This is wrong, you should use SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN instead, not a PAT that is manually created

Comment: The `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` approach is indeed a lot cleaner it would seem. I don't see how the PAT approach is "wrong", you haven't provided a well reasoned response. I'd agree though it's not the most efficient usage of PATs in this context. Manual creation, expiry etc all make it very cumbersome. I have added another answer showing how `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` can be used.

Comment: Additionally, I find having to modify the pipeline YML file simply to expose an environment variable a bit annoying. I would've expected the `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` (or more accurately `System.AccessToken`) variable to be just accessible in Cake out of the box, same as `BUILD_BUILDNUMBER` variable is.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by both @KevinSmith and @NickTurner, a better approach to accessing the VSTS feed is by using the pre-defined system variable `System.AccessToken` as opposed to using limited validity, manually created and cumbersome PATs. This variable is available on the build agents for the current build to use. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken).

One way of using this token in the Cake script is as follows:

First, expose the system variable as an environment variable for the Cake task in `azure-pipelines.yml`

```
steps:
- task: cake-build.cake.cake-build-task.Cake@0
  displayName: 'Cake '
  inputs:
    target: Pack
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Then in Cake you can access it like you would any environment variable, so in my case:

```
if (!NuGetHasSource(source:feed.Source))
{
    Information($"Nuget feed {feed.Source} not found, adding...");      

    var nugetSourceSettings = new NuGetSourcesSettings
                            {
                                UserName = "whoosywhatsit",
                                Password = EnvironmentVariable("SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"),
                                Verbosity = NuGetVerbosity.Detailed
                            };      

    NuGetAddSource(
        name:feed.Name,
        source:feed.Source,
        settings:nugetSourceSettings);
}
```

This seems to work! If there are better approaches of accessing this variable in Cake please let me know. **Please also note** in my case, I am only using this to restore packages from my VSTS feed, not for pushing to it. That I do via a `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task in the YML like so:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet nuget push'
  inputs:
    command: push
    packagesToPush: 'artifacts/package.nupkg'
    publishVstsFeed: '<id of my VSTS feed>'
```

And Azure pipeline handles the rest.